# Artifacts when smoke and glass interact

Tags: rendering, animation, smoke-simulation, glass, artifacts

https://youtu.be/_YHDpam17fs

Can anyone think of an obvious reason the mug and the smoke simulation create these weird artifacts? The setup should in theory be pretty simple. I can post the blend file if anyone wants it. I've gone nuts researching and trying different things to fix it.

Comment: I'm going to guess that Blender doesn't like parts of the smoke intersecting with the glass. Try adding a new domain object that doesn't touch the glass, rerun the sim and see if that helps at all.

Comment: Yeah I thought that too, but the smoke domain isn't interesting with the glass at all: https://imgur.com/a/sKIVK6X